# Вопрос по synchronized

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Я правильно понимаю, что если начал выполняться `synchronized` блок кода, пока он не выполнится, java не перескочит на другой поток?

Если это так, то зачем в блок `synchronized` помещают одно выражение, например инициализацию переменной, если java не может перескочить на другой поток, не выполнив хотя бы одну операцию, т.к. половину операции выполнить нельзя?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Блок `synchronized` в *Java* обладает тем свойством, что если в этот блок вошёл один поток, то другой поток сможет войти в этот блок не раньше, чем из него выйдет первый. Проще говоря, если один поток выполняет блок `synchronized`, другие потоки, желающие выполнить этот блок, будут ожидать.

Иногда считают, что если один поток вошёл в `synchronized`-блок, то все другие потоки приостанавливаются. Это неверно. Другие потоки продолжают выполняться до тех пор, пока они не "наткнутся" на этот же блок.

Но на самом деле всё немного сложнее. Блок `synchronized` использует в качестве "барьера" некоторый объект (что-то, являющееся потомком `java.lang.Object`, поэтому на `int` синхронизироваться не удастся). Если объявить два блока с синхронизацией на одном и том же объекте, то если один блок выполняется, другие потоки не смогут войти ***ни в один*** из этих блоков. Пример:

```
Object o;

synchronized(o) {
    // Блок 1
}

synchronized(o) {
    // Блок 2
}
```

Если какой-либо поток выполняет блок 1, то ***никакой*** поток не сможет в это же время выполнить блок 2. И наоборот, если какой-либо поток выполняет блок 2, то ***никакой*** поток не сможет в это же время выполнить блок 1.

Также следует отметить, что у класса могут быть `synchronized`-методы:

```
class Test {
    public synchronized void f() { /* ... */ }
    public synchronized void g() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Здесь неявно предполагается, что синхронизирующим объектом является экземпляр класса. Иными словами, если какой-либо поток вошёл в один из `synchronized`-методов экземпляра класса, то никакой другой поток не сможет войти ***ни в один*** из других `synchronized`-методов этого экземпляра. Но нужно иметь в виду, что другой поток сможет войти в `synchronized`-метод ***другого экземпляра*** того же самого класса. (Возможно, будет понятнее, если я скажу, что в данном случае синхронизация происходит на `this`.)

---

Перейдём теперь ко второй части вопроса. Почему инициализацию переменной выносят в `synchronized`-блок? Потому что утверждение об атомарности одной *Java*-операции неверно. Даже следующий оператор

```
int i = 0;
```

в общем случае может не быть атомарным. Дело в том, что  *атомарность* означает невозможность "увидеть" промежуточное состояние операции. Например, вышеуказанный код может быть скомпилирован в ***две*** процессорных инструкции:

```
xor eax,eax
mov [i], eax
```

Если другой поток "вклинится" между `xor` и `mov`, то он "увидит" промежуточное состояние. Что уж говорить про более сложные инициализации типа

```
String s = "строка";
```

и уж тем более

```
Object o = big_ang_long_running_function();
```

Comment: по-моему тут вкралась небольшая очепятка: "Дело в том, что атомарность означает возможность прервать операцию между двумя операциями процесора". Должно быть: "Дело в том, что атомарность означает **не**возможность прервать операцию между двумя операциями процесора"

Comment: @Sergi Спасибо. Поправил.

Comment: @kff спасибо большое, очень хорошее объяснение, жаль нельзя два раза + поставить)

Answer (score 0):

Нет. В конструкции `synchronized` передается указатель на некий объект. Так вот Java гарантирует, что при вызове такого блока, второй поток, который вызовет `synchronized` **с тем же** объектом, заснет, пока не выполнится первый блок